# Java KeyEvent & Syntax Highlighting

Tags: java, keyevent, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a syntax highlighting text editor in Java and I've run into a bit of a problem as to what I *should* do as opposed to what I want to do. Basically the KeyEvent class provides me with a bit of a problem:

1. KeyTyped does not allow me to ID
   what the key is so it is useless for
   lexing.
2. KeyPressed is better, it allows me
   to ID each key as it is pressed
   which is great for lexing, however
   it triggers the event before the key
   is actually put into the
   JEditorPane.
3. KeyReleased solves the problem of
   both KeyPressed & KeyTyped as it
   occurs after the character has been
   input and it allows me to actually
   ID what the character is. However if
   I hold 'a' and it puts in 50 'a's,
   I'm screwed.

My solution to the issue is to use KeyPressed for all characters that are to be input, consume the event, read the character that was supposed to be input and manually input it, however I'm guessing this isn't the most elegant solution available. My question is how else could I go about this? Is there something I'm just glazing over or did I find the solution to my problem and should just roll with it?

Comment: It's important to differentiate whether you want what *key* was pressed or what *character* was typed as a result of one or more key presses.  You question seems to vacillate between wanting one and then the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using a [Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) appears to be the opposite of what you say for KeyEvent:

> The getKeyChar method always returns a
>   valid Unicode character or
>   CHAR_UNDEFINED. Character input is
>   reported by KEY_TYPED events:
>   KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events
>   are not necessarily associated with
>   character input. Therefore, the result
>   of the getKeyChar method is guaranteed
>   to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED
>   events.

Comment: `For key pressed and key released events, the getKeyCode method returns the event's keyCode. For key typed events, the getKeyCode method always returns VK_UNDEFINED.` I'm thinking thinking about getting the key code.

Comment: Interesting, what do you want to do with the code?  You question sounds like you want to parse the text with each new character.